# Is there a way to automatically switch between pulseaudio sound profiles?

Tags: linux-mint, audio, bluetooth

I am on linux mint, and use bluetooth headphones a lot. There are two profiles, HSP/HFP and A2DP. Is there a way to have it set to A2DP, but switch to HSP/HFP when the mic is needed (like i join a discord or skype call), and then switch back when its no longer needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you pulseaudio version supports, but:
on `/etc/pulse/default.pa`: (normally this lines already exists but without `auto_switch`)

```
load-module module-bluetooth-policy auto_switch=2
```

the auto-switch profile do the job automagically